# What is the deal with the 1980s atmosphere of Netflix's "Sex Education"?

Tags: sex-education

Netflix's ***Sex Education*** is an odd duck: the show contains plenty of modern technology (most prominently smartphones), yet it often breathes a 1980s look & feel. Its soundtrack mainly consists of 1980s tracks, even when it involves music that teenagers are listening to.

What accounts for these anachronisms?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this article in *Cosmopolitan*](https://www.cosmopolitan.com/uk/entertainment/a25944377/when-is-sex-education-netflix-set/), the anachronisms are deliberate:

> **Emma Mackey** - who plays the wonderfully whip-smart Maeve, and is the
>   real brains behind Otis' operation - and **Ncuti Gatwa**, who stars as
>   Otis' out-and-proud best friend - told Cosmopolitan.com/uk the reason
>   behind the show's '80s feel.
>
> **"The whole aesthetic of the show is completely inspired by John Hughes
>   and that '80s high school aesthetic that we all know and love, and
>   it's quite universal,"** Emma explained.
>
> A few of John Hughes' fan favourites include *Pretty in Pink*, *Sixteen
>   Candles*, and *The Breakfast Club*.
>
> **"There are a whole range of films that we loved growing up, and that's
>   why the production team chose that because it works and it appeals to
>   people," she added.**
>
> "It's almost nostalgic in the way we tried to add that classic high
>   school, and pushed the heart and soul with a British twist; with a bit
>   of British seasoning," Ncuti added.
>
> Emma joked: "Yeah [otherwise] we'd all be heads down on our phones,
>   and it would be quite a boring show!"

Gillian Anderson confirms this in [an interview with TV Insider](https://www.tvinsider.com/742926/sex-education-netflix-gillian-anderson-asa-butterfield-john-hughes/):

> If *Sex Education* sounds less like stuffy British fare and more like
>   American teen comedies of the '80s, such as *The Breakfast Club*, that's
>   no accident. Says Anderson, **"Our executive producer was obsessed with
>   [John Hughes films] and was trying to find something that was going to
>   fit the bill."**

Series creator [**Laurie Nunn** talked to *Thrillist*](https://www.thrillist.com/entertainment/nation/sex-education-netflix-ending-explained-season-2) about the show:

> **Thrillist:** There is an '80s vibe to the show, in the costuming and the
>   music choices. Why did you want to tap into that aesthetic?
>
> **Nunn:** It was a very conscious decision from myself and the producers
>   and director **Ben Taylor** who is also an executive producer on the
>   project. **We all absolutely love the teen genre, particularly the John
>   Hughes films of the 1980s so we really wanted to make the show have
>   the feeling that it's an homage or that it has this nostalgic
>   backdrop, but that we are talking about very contemporary, modern
>   themes and storylines for the characters.** So in a way we were also
>   trying to take this tried and tested tropes of the genre and sort of
>   flip them on their head and show a different perspective on it. I
>   think those two things together and then with the Britishness just
>   make it feel like it's its own thing.

[From Mashable](https://mashable.com/article/sex-education-sex-scenes-me-too-teen-genre/):

> Nunn's exploration of the universality of being an awkward, sexually
>   inexperienced 16 year old is inspired by her love of iconic teen
>   movies and TV shows and the YA genre. "We really wanted to pay homage
>   to the John Hughes films of 1980s," said Nunn. **Netflix's commissioning
>   editor Alex Sapot described the series as "a real homage to John
>   Hughes, the '80s" and "an interesting intersection" of the John Hughes
>   aesthetic and Laurie Nunn's modern voice.** Nunn added that their aim
>   was to harness this inspiration and "take tried and tested tropes and
>   subvert them and look at them from a new perspective."