# Why does Otis's sweater have his name stitched on "Sex Education"?

Tags: sex-education

In episode 6 and 8 of *Sex Education* S1, we see a sweater in Maeve's house bearing Otis Milburn's name stitched onto the inside. I get why the writers used it to let us know that the sweater belongs to Otis but why does a sweater have a stitched name of the owner, rather than a brand or company's stitch?

Answer (score 5):

I am pretty sure it was something his mom did. The show makes her out to be a bit intrusive and she still tends to cottle him. Children commonly get their name stitched into their clothes so it shows that she still treats him like a kid.

Comment: You could add _why_ children get their names stitched into their clothes: to avoid the clothes of multiple children get mixed up in kindergarten or a summer camp

Comment: Even older children in 1980s Britain might have their names in clothing , school uniforms worn be many until they reached 16 are all pretty similar. For those going to 6th form the ability to wear their own clothes was a major novelty, (not very one did some got jobs, went to colleges of higher education, or joined the dole).

Answer (score 0):

In back to the future, Marty is called Calvin (or Pierre or Levi) in 1955 because that's the name written on his underwear.
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088763/trivia?item=tr2191807

According to my own experience, when my grandma stitched me sweater when I was young, while she didn't stich my all name (it's quite long), she at least stitched my Initial on the inside.

There is a french joke about a kid in a summer camp that was called '100% cotton' for the duration of the camp. The joke does not need to explain why.

It might be an 'old thing', something from the 80s or even before. Millenniums probably don't get the 'joke'.
I didn't watch this show, but I think I heard they wanted to give it a 80s vibe. This is exactly the kind of easter egg that would help giving this kind of vibe.

Comment: WRTT the 1980s vibe: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96706/what-is-the-deal-with-the-1980s-atmosphere-of-netflixs-sex-education